# Проблема с выводом первого элемента в списке

Tags: python, алгоритм, list

Моя функция должна выводить отличающуюся строку по составу букв, но она сталкивается с проблемой когда это строка первая в списке

```
def find_uniq(arr):
    a = arr.copy()
    b = arr

    for i in range(len(b)):
        b[i]=b[i].lower()
    print(b)
    print(a[0])
    for j in range(len(b)):
        if set(b[j]) != set(b[j+1]):
            print(a[j+1])
            return a[j+1]
        else:
           pass
```

Comment: тест кейс
['o', 's', 's', 's']
['s', 'o', 's', 's']
['s', 's', 'o', 's']
['s', 's', 's', 'o']

Comment: Форматирование поехало.

Comment: @Alpensin вы не могли бы подсказать как его исправить, буду благодарен

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Как отредактировать сообщение с вопросом или непонятен синтаксис питона?

Comment: @Alpensin мне понятно в чем проблема, когда элемент первый я все так же могу вывести только элемент J+1, мне бы хотелось ее решить и выводить элемент когда он первый в списке

Comment: Посмотрите на код в своем вопросе. Скопируйте его в ide и попробуйте запустить. У вас форматирование текста в вопросе поехало

Comment: @Alpensin спасибо я понял что вы хотели донести до меня, я исправил код, но это не помогло мне найти решение

Comment: else: pass не имеет никакого смысла, поэтому можно и нужно убрать

Comment: Что такое `отличающуюся строку по составу букв`? В вашем тест-кейсе вроде все "составы букв" одинаковые.